# System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteException: unable to open database file (An exception occurred while initializing the database)

Tags: sqlite, entity-framework-6

I am trying to use [SQLiteCodeFirst](https://github.com/msallin/SQLiteCodeFirst) with Entity Framework 6.2 and VS2017 15.9.4 to create a simple database.

However the database does not create.

Here is the DbContext

```
public class HelloDbContext : DbContext
{
    public HelloDbContext()
        : base("name=ConnectionString")
    {
    }


    public DbSet<Setting> Settings { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {

        var sqliteConnectionInitializer = new SqliteCreateDatabaseIfNotExists<HelloDbContext>(modelBuilder);
        Database.SetInitializer(sqliteConnectionInitializer);
    }
}
```

Here is the data entity class

```
   public class Setting
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Value { get; set; }
    }
```

Here is the code that the exception occurs in

```
    using (var ctx = new HelloDbContext())
        {

            try
            {
                var obj = new Setting { Name = "blue" };

                ctx.Settings.Add(obj);
                ctx.SaveChanges();
            }
            catch (Exception  ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex);
                throw;
            }

        }
```

Here is app.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false"/>
  </configSections>

  <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2" />
    </startup>

  <system.data>
    <DbProviderFactories>
      <remove invariant="System.Data.SQLite.EF6" />
      <add name="SQLite Data Provider (Entity Framework 6)"
           invariant="System.Data.SQLite.EF6"
           description=".NET Framework Data Provider for SQLite (Entity Framework 6)"
           type="System.Data.SQLite.EF6.SQLiteProviderFactory, System.Data.SQLite.EF6" />
      <remove invariant="System.Data.SQLite" />
      <add name="SQLite Data Provider" invariant="System.Data.SQLite"
           description=".Net Framework Data Provider for SQLite"
           type="System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteFactory, System.Data.SQLite" />
    </DbProviderFactories>
  </system.data>
  <entityFramework>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SQLite.EF6"
                type="System.Data.SQLite.EF6.SQLiteProviderServices, System.Data.SQLite.EF6" />
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient"
                type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SQLite"
                type="System.Data.SQLite.EF6.SQLiteProviderServices, System.Data.SQLite.EF6" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="ConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=c:\mydb.sqlite" providerName="System.Data.SQLite"/>

  </connectionStrings>

</configuration>
```

Here is the exception

```
   {System.Data.DataException: An exception occurred while initializing the database. See the InnerException for details. ---> System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityException: The underlying provider failed on Open. ---> System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteException: unable to open database file
   at System.Data.SQLite.SQLite3.Open(String strFilename, String vfsName, SQLiteConnectionFlags connectionFlags, SQLiteOpenFlagsEnum openFlags, Int32 maxPoolSize, Boolean usePool)
   at System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteConnection.Open()
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbConnectionDispatcher.<Open>b__36(DbConnection t, DbConnectionInterceptionContext c)
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.InternalDispatcher`1.Dispatch[TTarget,TInterceptionContext](TTarget target, Action`2 operation, TInterceptionContext interceptionContext, Action`3 executing, Action`3 executed)
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbConnectionDispatcher.Open(DbConnection connection, DbInterceptionContext interceptionContext)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.EntityConnection.<Open>b__2()
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DefaultExecutionStrategy.Execute(Action operation)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.EntityConnection.Open()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.EntityConnection.Open()
   at System.Data.Entity.DbContextTransaction.EnsureOpenConnection()
   at System.Data.Entity.DbContextTransaction..ctor(EntityConnection connection)
   at System.Data.Entity.Database.BeginTransaction()
   at SQLite.CodeFirst.SqliteInitializerBase`1.InitializeDatabase(TContext context)
   at SQLite.CodeFirst.SqliteCreateDatabaseIfNotExists`1.InitializeDatabase(TContext context)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.<>c__DisplayClassf`1.<CreateInitializationAction>b__e()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.PerformInitializationAction(Action action)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.PerformInitializationAction(Action action)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.PerformDatabaseInitialization()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.<InitializeDatabase>b__4(InternalContext c)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.RetryAction`1.PerformAction(TInput input)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeDatabaseAction(Action`1 action)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeDatabase()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.Initialize()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.GetEntitySetAndBaseTypeForType(Type entityType)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.Initialize()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.get_InternalContext()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.ActOnSet(Action action, EntityState newState, Object entity, String methodName)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.Add(Object entity)
   at System.Data.Entity.DbSet`1.Add(TEntity entity)
   at HelloSQLite.Form1.button1_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in d:\dev\helloSQLite\HelloSQLite\Form1.cs:line 29}
    [System.Data.DataException]: {System.Data.DataException: An exception occurred while initializing the database. See the InnerException for details. ---> System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityException: The underlying provider failed on Open. ---> System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteException: unable to open database file
   at System.Data.SQLite.SQLite3.Open(String strFilename, String vfsName, SQLiteConnectionFlags connectionFlags, SQLiteOpenFlagsEnum openFlags, Int32 maxPoolSize, Boolean usePool)
   at System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteConnection.Open()
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbConnectionDispatcher.<Open>b__36(DbConnection t, DbConnectionInterceptionContext c)
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.InternalDispatcher`1.Dispatch[TTarget,TInterceptionContext](TTarget target, Action`2 operation, TInterceptionContext interceptionContext, Action`3 executing, Action`3 executed)
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbConnectionDispatcher.Open(DbConnection connection, DbInterceptionContext interceptionContext)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.EntityConnection.<Open>b__2()
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DefaultExecutionStrategy.Execute(Action operation)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.EntityConnection.Open()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.EntityConnection.Open()
   at System.Data.Entity.DbContextTransaction.EnsureOpenConnection()
   at System.Data.Entity.DbContextTransaction..ctor(EntityConnection connection)
   at System.Data.Entity.Database.BeginTransaction()
   at SQLite.CodeFirst.SqliteInitializerBase`1.InitializeDatabase(TContext context)
   at SQLite.CodeFirst.SqliteCreateDatabaseIfNotExists`1.InitializeDatabase(TContext context)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.<>c__DisplayClassf`1.<CreateInitializationAction>b__e()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.PerformInitializationAction(Action action)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.PerformInitializationAction(Action action)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.PerformDatabaseInitialization()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.<InitializeDatabase>b__4(InternalContext c)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.RetryAction`1.PerformAction(TInput input)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeDatabaseAction(Action`1 action)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeDatabase()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.Initialize()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.GetEntitySetAndBaseTypeForType(Type entityType)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.Initialize()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.get_InternalContext()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.ActOnSet(Action action, EntityState newState, Object entity, String methodName)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.Add(Object entity)
   at System.Data.Entity.DbSet`1.Add(TEntity entity)
   at HelloSQLite.Form1.button1_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in d:\dev\helloSQLite\HelloSQLite\Form1.cs:line 29}
    _className: "System.Data.DataException"
    _data: null
    _dynamicMethods: null
    _exceptionMethod: null
    _exceptionMethodString: null
    _helpURL: null
    _HResult: -2146233087
    _innerException: {System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityException: The underlying provider failed on Open. ---> System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteException: unable to open database file
   at System.Data.SQLite.SQLite3.Open(String strFilename, String vfsName, SQLiteConnectionFlags connectionFlags, SQLiteOpenFlagsEnum openFlags, Int32 maxPoolSize, Boolean usePool)
   at System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteConnection.Open()
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbConnectionDispatcher.<Open>b__36(DbConnection t, DbConnectionInterceptionContext c)
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.InternalDispatcher`1.Dispatch[TTarget,TInterceptionContext](TTarget target, Action`2 operation, TInterceptionContext interceptionContext, Action`3 executing, Action`3 executed)
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbConnectionDispatcher.Open(DbConnection connection, DbInterceptionContext interceptionContext)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.EntityConnection.<Open>b__2()
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DefaultExecutionStrategy.Execute(Action operation)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.EntityConnection.Open()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.EntityConnection.Open()
   at System.Data.Entity.DbContextTransaction.EnsureOpenConnection()
   at System.Data.Entity.DbContextTransaction..ctor(EntityConnection connection)
   at System.Data.Entity.Database.BeginTransaction()
   at SQLite.CodeFirst.SqliteInitializerBase`1.InitializeDatabase(TContext context)
   at SQLite.CodeFirst.SqliteCreateDatabaseIfNotExists`1.InitializeDatabase(TContext context)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.<>c__DisplayClassf`1.<CreateInitializationAction>b__e()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.PerformInitializationAction(Action action)}
    _ipForWatsonBuckets: 18474291
    _message: "An exception occurred while initializing the database. See the InnerException for details."
    _remoteStackIndex: 0
    _remoteStackTraceString: null
    _safeSerializationManager: {System.Runtime.Serialization.SafeSerializationManager}
    _source: null
    _stackTrace: {sbyte[384]}
    _stackTraceString: null
    _watsonBuckets: null
    _xcode: -532462766
    _xptrs: 0
    Data: {System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal}
    HelpLink: null
    HResult: -2146233087
    InnerException: {System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityException: The underlying provider failed on Open. ---> System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteException: unable to open database file
   at System.Data.SQLite.SQLite3.Open(String strFilename, String vfsName, SQLiteConnectionFlags connectionFlags, SQLiteOpenFlagsEnum openFlags, Int32 maxPoolSize, Boolean usePool)
   at System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteConnection.Open()
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbConnectionDispatcher.<Open>b__36(DbConnection t, DbConnectionInterceptionContext c)
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.InternalDispatcher`1.Dispatch[TTarget,TInterceptionContext](TTarget target, Action`2 operation, TInterceptionContext interceptionContext, Action`3 executing, Action`3 executed)
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbConnectionDispatcher.Open(DbConnection connection, DbInterceptionContext interceptionContext)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.EntityConnection.<Open>b__2()
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DefaultExecutionStrategy.Execute(Action operation)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.EntityConnection.Open()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.EntityConnection.Open()
   at System.Data.Entity.DbContextTransaction.EnsureOpenConnection()
   at System.Data.Entity.DbContextTransaction..ctor(EntityConnection connection)
   at System.Data.Entity.Database.BeginTransaction()
   at SQLite.CodeFirst.SqliteInitializerBase`1.InitializeDatabase(TContext context)
   at SQLite.CodeFirst.SqliteCreateDatabaseIfNotExists`1.InitializeDatabase(TContext context)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.<>c__DisplayClassf`1.<CreateInitializationAction>b__e()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.PerformInitializationAction(Action action)}
    IPForWatsonBuckets: 18474291
    IsTransient: false
    Message: "An exception occurred while initializing the database. See the InnerException for details."
    RemoteStackTrace: null
    Source: "EntityFramework"
    StackTrace: "   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.PerformInitializationAction(Action action)\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.PerformDatabaseInitialization()\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.<InitializeDatabase>b__4(InternalContext c)\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.RetryAction`1.PerformAction(TInput input)\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeDatabaseAction(Action`1 action)\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeDatabase()\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.Initialize()\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.GetEntitySetAndBaseTypeForType(Type entityType)\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.Initialize()\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.get_InternalContext()\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.ActOnSet(Action action, EntityState newState, Object entity, String methodName)\r\n   at System.Data.En
tity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.Add(Object entity)\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.DbSet`1.Add(TEntity entity)\r\n   at HelloSQLite.Form1.button1_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in d:\\dev\\helloSQLite\\HelloSQLite\\Form1.cs:line 29"
    TargetSite: {Void PerformInitializationAction(System.Action)}
    WatsonBuckets: null
```

Here are the references

[image: References]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like a permission issue

```
    System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteException: unable to open database file
```

The database-file is set to *c:\mydb.sqlite* in app.config connectionString

```
    <connectionStrings>
      <add name="ConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=c:\mydb.sqlite" providerName="System.Data.SQLite"/>
    </connectionStrings>
```

Windows is kinda weird at times with files in the system-disk root (try creating a text-file in on system-disk root *c:\* with the rightclick-menu-thingy).
You could change the filepath for the connectionString in app.config to a newly created folder, say  *c:\testing-stuffs\mydb.sqlite* (im wildy guessing there is nothing created at *c:\mydb.sqlite* so there should be no file to move).

Comment: Ah thankyou, the thought crossed my mind but since I had copied the example I did not double check . It must have been ok to do once upon a time.